# Best point to jump off a plane to skydive to destination in fastest time?

Tags: calculus, geometry

Consider a plane moving at constant velocity from west to east as shown in the illustration below.

The goal is to calculate the optimal distance from the target to jump off the plane, in order to reach the target on the ground in the fastest amount of time possible.

In most real-world cases, since the plane is moving very fast, you would wait until the target is almost perpendicular to the plane's path and jump then.

However, in non-real-world cases, if you can imagine the plane moving very slowly, then you would want to jump earlier, at point B or even point A, as the jumper's skydiving velocity dominates over the plane's.

Another way of looking at the problem is this- the trade-off comes down to moving very quickly in ***one*** axis (plane's path) versus moving/skydiving more slowly through ***three*** axes.

Other important assumptions/simplifications: after jumping, the air drag will immediately cause the horizontal (x-axis) velocity of the skydiver to drop to zero. Also, the skydiver's velocity towards the target (ground speed) has a known/fixed value that kicks-in immediately upon jumping. So regardless of plane's speed, weather, etc., when the skydiver jumps, he will move towards the target with a fixed ground speed and fall towards the ground at a fixed speed.

**How do I come up with an expression for optimal distance from target to jump in terms of plane's altitude, plane's velocity, target's distance from plane's path, and skydiver's velocity?** We can ignore all accelerations. i.e. plane has constant velocity, skydiver has constant/terminal velocity and is immediately realized upon jumping, etc.

[Illustration showing plane's path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/30nlf.jpg)

Comment: Keep in mind that when the jumper leaves the plane, they will already be moving horizontally at the speed of the plane (at the point when they jumped out). If you want to assume constant vertical velocity, there is only one place to jump that will get the jumper to the target.

Comment: I meant to address this in my original post. I will add the following: "Assume that once the jumper jumps from the plane, their horizontal velocity will be zero."

Comment: in that case they will miss the target unless they jump from directly above it

Comment: Alex, you are correct. I added more details. The jumper generates their own ground speed immediately upon jumping, which has a fixed value.

Answer (score 1):

The skydiver should jump at the point that will get them to land at the desired point using horizontal velocity along the path of the plane because that is the earliest he can jump.  Assess the time of the fall by dividing the altitude by the downward velocity.  Multiply that time by the horizontal speed of the skydiver to get the horizontal distance.  Jump that far from the target.